# understand Firebase querying better

Tags: firebase

Suppose I have the following data in a firebase database:

```
things: {
    1: { name: "apple" }
    2: { name: "banana" }
    3: { name: "cherry" }
    4: { name: "date" }
    5: { name: "elderberry" }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to have a cloud function that retrieves only the items with names matching a particular string (e.g. "anana" would return [{ name: "banana" }]), but this appears to be impossible with Firebase? I think?

The next best thing would be a search that looks for items with names starting with a particular string (so "anana" would return [] but "ban" would return [{ name: "banana" }]).

This is what I would expect it to look like:

```
const things = admin.database().ref('/things')
await things.orderByChild("name")
    .startAt(queryText)
    .endAt(queryText + "\uf8ff")
    .limitToFirst(3)
    .get(snapshot => {
    result.send(snapshot.val());
}
```

and what I would expect to get from this is something like [{ key: 2, name: "banana" }, { key: 3, name: "cherry" }, { key: 4, name: "date" }].

but alas, I don't understand why, but there is no get() function - from the documentation and threads I can find discussing the subject, it looks like the solution to this particular problem involves .on('child_added'...) but this doesn't make sense to me, and it doesn't work. What does 'child_added' mean? The explanation here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data) is not helpful at all. It sounds like they're talking about listeners, which is completely unrelated, which is really confusing. I just want to get data when I ask for it.

I've tried every variation I can think of using on(), once(), "value", "child_added", etc... and I can retrieve either the entire table, just the last item, or nothing, depending on the combination, but the code I write and the results I get never seem to correlate logically. It's not ordering by the child attribute value, it's not limiting the results to 3, and it's not starting or ending at the specified values. Nothing seems to be working the way it's supposed to according to documentation.

I think I'm missing something fundamental about how firebase works. Can anyone help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

You are using real time database, the method `on()` or `once()` is used when retrieving data.

So you need to use the following code:

```
const things = admin.database().ref('/things')
await things.orderByChild("name")
    .startAt(queryText)
    .endAt(queryText + "\uf8ff")
    .limitToFirst(3)
    .on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    result.send(snapshot.val());
}
```

`orderByChild('name').startAt(queryText).endAt(queryText + "\uf8ff")` is the same as saying in sql:

`WHERE name LIKE 'bana%';`

`limitToFirst(3)` will get the first 3 in the database if they satisfy the condition that they start with `bana`

Check the following docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, that's what the documentation says, and that's what I tried, but it doesn't work. I get null returned to my browser when I test it. I can even see the text query ("b" - so it should get most of them) in the firebase logs. However when I remove "endAt()", I get the whole table. It doesn't start at 'b' and it doesn't limit to 3. I've checked, double-checked, and triple-checked, and everything I'm doing should be right. I know my functions are being deployed, because everything looks right in firebase console, except for the snapshot. I am extremely confuzzled.

Comment: Ok, it's not the whole table, it is _kind of_ limiting to 3 - I get a list with 2 nulls, then 3 seemingly random objects, so the length is superficially 5

Comment: Does it make sense to get the entire list of entries and loop through them, since it's a cloud function? There could be hundreds of thousands of entries, so I would never do something like that on the front end (I mainly do font end work, so this is entering unfamiliar territory)... is that something reasonable to do with a cloud function, since it's on the server?

Comment: Should I be using something other than Firebase for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: use firestore instead of real time database, you can do better queries